# Advansed xlsx spreadsheet formatting

Tags: javascript, excel, go, xlsx

Is there some JavaScript or Golang lib that allows to create `xlsx` files using some custom heavy formatting?

I'm working on an Electron app and want to generate some reports but 
[the most popular](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library doesn't provide **cell formatting**, [that fork](https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx) looses the ability to define page properties like **margins** and **page orientation** and [that Golang lib](https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) as I see doesn't provide **page properties** too.

Can anybody show some good alternatives or show me I'm wrong?
(no C-like langs and Python please)

Answer (score 0):

I am myself looking for something similar to format docx documents and I have just started trying out [gooxml](https://github.com/baliance/gooxml).

Currently it has following capabilities for Excel:

- Read/Write/Edit
- Cell formatting including conditional formatting
- Cell validation (drop down combobox, rules, etc.)
- Retrieve cell values as formatted by Excel (e.g. retrieve a date or number as displayed in Excel)
- Formula Evaluation (100+ functions supported currently, more will be added as required)
- Embedded Images
- All chart types

**Edit to answer comment:**
As stated in the documentation, you may have to fall back to raw document manipulation should the library's API not cover a specific use case.

See [CT_PageMargins.go](https://github.com/baliance/gooxml/blob/master/schema/soo/sml/CT_PageMargins.go) and [CT_PageSetup.go](https://github.com/baliance/gooxml/blob/master/schema/soo/sml/CT_PageSetup.go) for margin and orientation...

Comment: Ok thanks thats something, but I still don't see page properties support like margins and page orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I've learned the lesson - after trying to use "super-hard-to-understand-and-use" jsreport-xlsx module I've remembered about [one lib](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) that didn't worked in Electron renderer and tried it to work from Electron main process.

And it works! Sometime it may be a little treaky to make it create doc exactly you want but it's much better than XLSX-style I've used before and have all features I want.

(it's second [and last I believe] time I've forget about Electron renderer is not Node.js, the true Node.js is main process)